# Division by zero error in votes

Tags: php, wordpress

I get division by zero error this functions. How do I fix it?

```
function percent($liked,$total_voting){
$liked = (int)$liked;
$total_voting = (int)$total_voting;
return ceil(($liked/$total_voting)*100);
```

Comment: What values are the arguments?

Comment: Just check if the $total_voting is zero before the calculations.

Comment: In PHP division by zero is a reported as an error but the program does not halt. What do you mean by fixing then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(It's testing if `$total_voting` is zero and returns in this case false)

```
function percent($liked, $total_voting) {

    if($total_voting == 0)
        return false;

    $liked = (int)$liked;
    $total_voting = (int)$total_voting;

    return ceil(($liked/$total_voting)*100);
}
```